# soap request with xml string parameter

Tags: php, xml, soap

May be there is few blog similar this but I can't solve the problem. I convert xml to string and try to pass it as a parameter. Then I got error. I try to slove it using cdata but it not solved my problem. At last I try to use SoapVar and getting following error

**MY CODE:**

> ```
> $survey =   $domtree->saveXML();    
> $soapVar = new SoapVar($survey,XSD_ANYXML); 
> $params = array(>        
>     "ManagerID" => 0,
>     "Reg_SalesCenterID" => $id,
>     "surveys" => $soapVar,
>     "SalesCenterList" => $SalesCenter);
>
> try {
>     $response = $soapClient->__soapCall('AddNewContact', array($params));
> }catch (SoapFault $fault) {
>     echo 'Request : <br/><xmp>',
>     $soapClient->__getLastRequest(),
>     '</xmp><br/><br/> Error Message : <br/>',
>     $fault->getMessage();
> }
> ```

**ERROR**

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'AddNewContactBestRent'. No characters can appear before the XML
>   declaration. Line 2, position 1385.

Comment: No its not solved my problem. Now error is " End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace "

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$response = $soapClient->__soapCall('AddNewContact', $params);
```

You wrapped an array in an array. Because `$params` var is already an array. But you have to pass a key => value array with scalar data to [`SoapClient::__soapCall()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapcall.php) method as second parameter.

Although this doesn't solve your `SoapVar` problem. But should get your `SoapClient::__soapCall()` method call working.